# getting parent directory of ${basedir} from maven

Tags: java, maven

Is there way to get parent directory for `${basedir}` in my pom.xml? Currently I have

```
<earSourceDirectory>${basedir}/EAR/src/main/resources</earSourceDirectory>
```

but I need to access parent directory of basedir as my resources lies in different maven project.

How can I get the parent folder of $`{basedir}`?

Comment: Have you tried `../${project.basedir}/`?

Comment: yes.. but not working... I tried to print with <echo message="../${project.basedir}"/> got output as  [echo] ../C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MavenEARExample\MavenEARExample-ear

Answer (score 14):

In the children:

```
<properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
</properties>
```

In the grandchildren:

```
<properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.parent.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
</properties>
```

Comment: @tribbloid What is added in Maven 3 instead of ${project.parent.parent.basedir}?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'project.parent.basedir'. This seems to not work anymore.

Answer (score 13):

```
${project.basedir}/../
```

However, access resources in a different module is something I try to avoid. I'd suggest using the [unpack goal of the maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html).

Comment: I am only getting output as C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MavenEARExample\MavenEARExample-ear/../   where as I expect the parent directory C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MavenEARExample\

Answer (score 7):

Please, don't try to go outside the basedir, because it's considered a very bad practice. 
Even if you succeed now, it will be the start of a workaround over workaround, trying to battle Maven. In the end, Maven will win.
If a developer checks out a directory with a `pom.xml`, it should be able run the project with `mvn verify` without any references to other directories.

If these are shared resources, make it a separate project and include it as a dependency (search for multi module projects). Or use the [maven-remote-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/) to pull these resources into your project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the requirement of moving zip generated in MainDirectory/Submodule/target/ to MainDirectory/target/.
I tried all solutions from everywhere but I was unable to solve. I finally tried Ant plugin in pom.xml of submodule to copy as below:

```
<plugin> 
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId> 
  <version>1.7</version> 
  <executions> 
    <execution> 
      <id>copy to parent target</id> 
      <phase>package</phase> 
      <goals> 
        <goal>run</goal> 
      </goals> 
      <configuration> 
        <target> 
           <copy todir="../target/" overwrite="true" flatten="true"> 
             <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/"/> 
           </copy> 
        </target> 
      </configuration> 
    </execution> 
  </executions> 
</plugin>
```